# Emu8086 - cannot open file

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox, emu8086

I have a problem with emu8086. I want to open a file, but when I try to emulate it, it shows me an error.

```
data1 segment
       in_file   db 'input.txt',0
       handle    dw ?
       warn      db "Error$"
data1 ends
code1 segment
    start1:
        mov ax,seg w_stosu
        mov ss,ax
        mov sp,offset w_stosu

        mov ax,seg in_file
        mov ds,ax
        mov dx,offset in_file
        mov ax,3d00h  
        int 21h
        jb  error   
        mov ds:[handle],ax
        mov ax,04c00h  
        int 21h
error:  
        mov dx,offset warn
        call    print_dx
        mov ax,04c00h  
        int 21h
print_dx:
        mov ax,seg data1
        mov ds,ax
        mov ah,9h  
        int 21h
ret
code1 ends

stack1 segment stack
                dw  255 dup(?)
      w_stosu   dw  ?
stack1 ends

end start1
```

The error appears at this part:

```
    mov ax,3d00h  
    int 21h
```

> file does not exist
>   C:\emu8086\MyBuild\input.txt
>   interrupt error: 21h/3Dh : cannot open file.

I have my input file (`input.txt`) in `C:\emu8086\vdrive\C` where it should be. When I compile it in MASM in `dosbox`, it works correctly. I don't know where may be the problem. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message you got hints, the emulator is looking for the file in `C:\emu8086\MyBuild`, because you didn't specify an absolute path containing a drive letter.

> DOS file system is emulated in C:\emu8086\vdrive\x (x is a drive letter)
>
> **If no drive letter is specified and current directory is not set, then C:\emu8086\MyBuild\
>   path is used by default.**

([source](http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_and_DOS_interrupts.pdf))

Comment: I have also that file in C:\emu8086\MyBuild\ and it shows the same error.